# Understanding how a branch is linking to a remote branch

Tags: git

I recently starting working on a project that uses Git for version control.

I thought I understood branching pretty well but I've noticed something weird.

[image]

Every time I push to origin/expenses it also pushes to dev-master, as if they were the same branch.

Why and how is this happening?

Comment: There's a couple odd things happening. Why is your local branch called `origin/expenses`? The remote branch is actually called `origin/origin/expenses`...? What's the output of `git push` when checked out on `origin/expenses`?

Comment: If I have nothing to push, is there a way to view what it would output? I literally just cloned the repo and this weird double origin branch already existed. It's thrown me because I can't even see it in the config. So I'm thinking maybe the upstream was set incorrectly?

Comment: It's not wrong, but it is confusing. As for why two branches push? Maybe there's a git hook doing that? It's quite hard to say with only an image to go by

Comment: I'll try and add more context, but its so strange.

Answer (score 2):

You made a *local* branch named `origin/expenses`.  [Have you ever been to a party where all the guys are named Bruce?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ojhtq51Ya8)

If you run:

```
git for-each-ref
```

this will spill out *all* refs: all (local) branch names, all tag names, all remote-tracking names, `refs/stash` if it exists, and any other names.  In each output line, Git will include the *full name* of each ref.

Calling a ref by its *full name* is how you express that it's in trouble, like when [Stella starts out saying: *Harcourt Fenton Mudd, what have you been up to?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ag1EbxYKh_4)

More seriously, it's how you tell whether something is a *branch* name, a *tag* name, or some other kind of name.  A ref whose *full name* starts with `refs/heads/` is a *branch* name.  A ref whose full name starts with `refs/tags/` is a tag name.  One that starts with `refs/remotes/` is a *remote-tracking name:* a name stored in your Git references database, that your Git makes to correspond to some other Git's *branch* name.

When you make your own branch named `origin/expenses`, Git still looks it up as `refs/heads/origin/expenses` and therefore realizes that it's a *branch* name, even though it starts with `origin/` once you strip away the `refs/heads/` part, as Git does for display purposes.  It is in fact possible to have both this *and* a remote-tracking name, `refs/remotes/origin/expenses`, which—when you strip off `refs/remotes/` for display purposes—is also spelled `origin/expenses`.  You're now at a Bruce-party.

*Git* can keep this straight.  You *could*, too, but ... you shouldn't bother.  Just rename your Bruce, er, branch.

Comment: Do you know why pushing would push another branch as well? (I couldn’t explain it)

Comment: @evolutionxbox: If the upstream setting of a local branch is another local branch, that would do it. I don't see that in the image (I assume blue-color = refs/remotes/ prefix) but in situations like this when I have seen people have them before, they've done all kinds of crazy things trying to fix it, resulting in all kinds of crazy results, which they then mis-attribute. Without a clear sequence of Git commands and results, it's hard to back-fill.

Comment: I will use what you've mentioned above and do some digging. The references were pretty amusing too.